# Printing a sharp barcode using Picturebox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing, picturebox, zxing

I have a question and i hope somebody can help me.

Im using the ZXing.Net plugin to generate a barcode from a number.
All is working well and i get a barcode in a picture box.
Now i would like to print this barcode but the image is all fuzzy.
I've been trying to get it more sharp this is my code now:

```
 Private Sub PrintDocument_BO_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument_BO.PrintPage

        Dim myBitmap1 As Bitmap = New Bitmap(PrintBackorder.picBarcode.Width, PrintBackorder.picBarcode.Height)
        PrintBackorder.picBarcode.DrawToBitmap(myBitmap1, New Rectangle(0, 0, PrintBackorder.picBarcode.Width, PrintBackorder.picBarcode.Height))
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap1, 625, 50)
 End sub
```

Is there something i could add or am i doing something wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: How did you *get a barcode in a picture box*? Did you set the `Image` property? What is its SizeMode? What is the size of this BarCode? Or are you painting it? -- Remove `SmoothingMode` and try  `InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor`.

Comment: Thank you Jimi, InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor did the trick!